# Pushing Data From Oracle Cloud to Google Cloud

Tags: oracle-cloud-infrastructure

I have a requirement to Have Oracle Cloud Data Pushed  to Google Cloud Storage . This is not Oracle On Prem , Essentially what will be the best way to have Oracle EDMCS Metadata  and Fusion Data from Oracle Cloud Object Storage pushed to  Cloud Cloud Storage .

Also , From Start of the Data Push from Oracle to Google Cloud , How can I have a End to End Monitoring as a Pipeline set up .

Answer (score 0):

I think that the best (simplest) way to do this is to create a notification when there is a new object in the object storage bucket, and, the the event triggers, call a serverless function to push the object to GCP.

Have you checked the Oracle Architecture Center?

[Oracle Architecture Center](https://docs.oracle.com/solutions/)

Specifically, here you have an example

[Deploy an event-triggered serverless application](https://docs.oracle.com/en/solutions/event-triggered-serverless-app/index.html)

Here, also, have a very interesting sample

[Oracle Cloud Infrastructure Events with APEX and ORDS](https://www.jmjcloud.com/blog/oracle-cloud-infrastructure-events-with-apex-and-ords)